# References and move vs. copy

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm reading through chapter 4 of the Rust book, coming from a Python background.

What confuses me a bit is that this doesn't compile:

```
fn do_something(s3: String) {
    println!("{}", s3);
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello");
    do_something(s);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

(as it shouldn't, because s is moved in the function call), but this does:

```
fn do_something(s3: &String) {
    println!("{}", s3);
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello");
    let s2 = &s1;
    do_something(s2);
    println!("{}", s2);
}
```

if I understand correctly, this is because s1 is already a pointer, so s2 is a pointer (well, a refrence) to a (stack-allocated) pointer. Therefore, s2 is copied in the function call and not moved. Is this so? Is the above the same as this?

```
fn main() {
    let a = 5;
    let b = &a;
    do_something(b);
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Comment: could you show `do_something()` please?

Comment: It merely prints the value again, does nothing of interest. Eg. `fn do_something(s3: String) {
    println!("{}", s3);
}`. In the second example I change the signature to `&String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> fn main() {
>     let s1 = String::from("Hello");
>     let s2 = &s1;
>     do_something(s2);
>     println!("{}", s2);
> }
> ```

This works because [references are `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-73). `s2` is copied, not moved, and can continue to be used after the call to `do_something`.

---

> Is the above the same as this?
>
> ```
> fn main() {
>     let a = 5;
>     let b = &a;
>     do_something(b);
>     println!("{}", b);
> }
> ```

Yes, it is. It doesn't matter if `a` or `s1` are `Copy`, only that `b` or `s2` are.

---

> I guess my question is, are they `Copy` because they are always pointers to stack-allocated data?

All shared references are `Copy` because of the blanket implementation:

> ```
> impl<'_, T> Copy for &'_ T
> where
>     T: ?Sized,
> ```

It doesn't matter where the references point, stack or heap or `.data` section or anywhere else. References are small word-sized values and it's convenient and efficient to copy them, so Rust makes them `Copy`.

That's the usual metric: Is copying efficient? `String`s aren't `Copy` because cloning them is an expensive *O*(*n*) operation. `&str`s, being references, *are* `Copy` because copying pointers is cheap.

(It's not the only metric, of course. Some types are not `Copy` because they are logically unique. For example, [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) is also just a pointer, but it's an owned type, not a shared reference.)

Comment: I guess my question is, are they Copy because they are always pointers to stack-allocated data? (in my second example, to another pointer)

Comment: @Cartucho Being [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) is a property of the type itself (it can be safely copied in a bitwise fashion), and not related to the fact that you decide to stack/heap allocate such a data.